# How can I check the status of an Australian visa application?

Tags: visas, australia, application-status

How do I find out the status of my australia visa application?  I applied at the same time as my wife.  She recieved hers within 24 hours.  It was done on 5/27/19 and I have not received a response.

Comment: Where did you apply? Online? Via an embassy or consulate?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you've applied online rather than at an embassy/consulate/visa office. If not, you should contact the place you submitted your application.

You should be able to check your application status via [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/ola/app).

The Australian Department of Home Affairs [says](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/tools/immiaccount):

> **Check your application status**
>
> If you applied online you can check your visa application status in [ImmiAccount](https://online.immi.gov.au/ola/app).
>
> We assign a status to your application to show progress.
>
> The status shows next to your application in 'My applications summary'.
>
> Incomplete means you have started but not completed an application.
>       Ready to submit means you have completed an application and can submit.
>       Submitted means you have submitted an application.
>       Received means we have received an application from you and can assess it within the current processing times.
>       Initial assessment means we are assessing your application.
>       Further assessment means we are assessing the information we requested from you.
>       Finalised means we have made a decision. We will notify you by email or post.
>
> Note: The application status for My Health Declarations and Partner sponsorship forms will always display a status of submitted and will not change to a status of received.

You can also [check the typical processing times, split by type of visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/global-visa-processing-times).

If you were applying for an ETA from certain countries, there is a [separate page to check the ETA application status](https://www.eta.homeaffairs.gov.au/ETAS3/etas?submit=check)